# How to db_select DISTINCT on a particular field in Drupal 7?

Tags: database

I understand that you can specify ->distinct() on the db_select statement so that it only returns distinct values when looking at ALL fields. But what I want is to return distinct values by only looking at ONE field. Here's my code:

```
$event_table = db_select('my_table', 'e')
    ->distinct()
    ->orderBy('e.time', 'ASC');//ORDER BY
$event_table->join('node', 'n', 'e.nid = n.nid'); //JOIN node with events
$event_table->groupBy('e.time');//GROUP BY time
$event_table->fields('e')//SELECT the fields from events
    ->fields('n',array('type','status','title'))//SELECT the fields from node
    ->orderBy('e.time', 'ASC');//ORDER BY

$result_event_table = $event_table->execute();
$result_event_table = $result_event_table->fetchAllAssoc('time');
```

Suppose I want the distinct column to be e.nid. You'd think  ->distinct('e.nid') would work but it still returns distinct values based on all fields (i.e. distinct(columns1, column2, column3, etc).

Comment: Any chance you could give a sample of the output SQL you're looking for? That would make it pretty easy to work out how to coax `db_select` into doing the same

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you're trying to get to roughly this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.nid AS nid, e.time AS time, n.type AS type, n.status AS status, n.title AS title
FROM 
{my_table} e
INNER JOIN {node} n ON n.nid = e.nid
GROUP BY e.time
ORDER BY e.time ASC
```

You would use:

```
$query = db_select('my_table', 'e')
  ->distinct()
  ->fields('e', array('nid', 'time', 'foo', 'bar'))
  ->fields('n', array('type', 'status', 'title'))
  ->groupBy('e.time')
  ->orderBy('e.time');

$query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = e.nid');
```

Comment: This just gives me all fields distinct, not just nid being distinct

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the above is a distinct query...what SQL are you trying to produce?

Comment: suppose there is '4' '4' '5' '5' in the nid column with a corresponding column named 'type' with 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'. well, if I select distinct on both columns (nid,type), the result will have 4 rows. but if i select distinct on JUST nid, the result will have 2 rows. I'm trying to select distinct on JUST nid

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how grouping works in SQL...to do what you're describing you'd need to remove the type column from the selected fields

Answer (score 6):

DISTINCT is actually a global post-modifier for SELECT, that is, as opposed to SELECT ALL (returning all answers) it is SELECT DISTINCT (returning all unique answers). So a single DISTINCT acts on ALL the columns that you give it.

This makes it real hard to use DISTINCT on a single column, while getting the other columns, without doing major extremely ugly backflips.

The correct answer is to use a GROUP BY on the columns that you want to have unique answers:

Comment: Exactly. That's why DBTNG has it on the query level. The only time DISTINCT is column level (or vaguely looks like it) is when you do `COUNT(DISTINCT foo)` but even then it's a modifier of the aggregator function.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `->distinct()` and replace it with `$event_table->AddExpression('distinct e.nid', 'nid');`

Like so:

```
$event_table = db_select('my_table', 'e');
$event_table->AddExpression('distinct e.nid', 'nid')
$event_table->orderBy('e.time', 'ASC');//ORDER BY
$event_table->join('node', 'n', 'e.nid = n.nid'); //JOIN node with events
$event_table->groupBy('e.time');//GROUP BY time

// you need to outline all fields here, can't use e.*
$event_table->fields('e')//SELECT the fields from events

    ->fields('n',array('type','status','title'))//SELECT the fields from node
    ->orderBy('e.time', 'ASC');//ORDER BY

$result_event_table = $event_table->execute();
$result_event_table = $result_event_table->fetchAllAssoc('time');
```

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct e.nid AS nid FROM mcc_notify_event_queue e INNER JOIN node n ON e.nid' at line 1: SELECT e.*, n.type AS type, n.status AS status, n.title AS title, distinct e.nid AS anid FROM {mcc_notify_event_queue} e INNER JOIN {node} n ON e.nid = n.nid GROUP BY e.time ORDER BY e.time ASC; Array ( )

Comment: can't use e.* and distinct e.nid, throws an error. You'll need to write out your fields as I've noted above.

Comment: I'm still getting an error. All I've done is change your code to $event_table->fields('e',array('nid','time','event_type'))//SELECT the fields from events

Comment: you're still selecting nid twice in that case which explains the error. Try $event_table->fields('e',array('time','event_type'))

Comment: still an error distinct e.nid AS nid FROM my_module_event_queue e INNER JOIN node n ON e.nid ' at line 1: SELECT e.time AS time, e.event_type AS event_type, n.type AS type, n.status AS status, n.title AS title, distinct e.nid AS nid FROM {my_module_event_queue} e INNER JOIN {node} n ON e.nid = n.nid GROUP BY e.time ORDER BY e.time ASC;

Answer (score -1):

If you use this query then, its provide proper distinct query.

```
<?php  

$select = db_select('service_payment_transaction','o');
$select->distinct('o.transaction_id');
$select->innerJoin('users', 'u', 'u.uid = o.user_id');
$select->fields('o');
$select->fields('u');
$select->condition('o.service_gv_code','','!=');
$select->range($start,$page_count);
$select->groupBy('o.service_gv_code');
$select->orderBy('transaction_id', 'DESC');
$result_query = $select->execute();
```

Comment: The [distinct function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Adistinct/7.x) takes a boolean as it's argument, not a string.